# Reformatting data sets in R data frame

Tags: r

I cleaned up a text output from a simulation which I performed. I produced a data frame in R which contains 19 similar data sets which are stacked vertically like this:

```
Data set 1
Data set 2
.
.
Data set 19
```

Each data set has 260 rows and 4 columns of data formatted like this:

```
A F 124 241
.
.
D Q 748 854
```

Since each data set contains the same values in columns 1 & 2, the entire data frame with 19 data sets has this form:

```
A F 124 241
.
.
D Q 748 856
A F 068 937
.
.
D Q 300 099
.
.
.
A F 175 235
.
.
D Q 725 893
```

I want to figure out how to stack the data sets horizontally instead. Since columns 1 & 2 are identical for all 19 data sets, from the second data set onwards, I only want to extract columns 3 & 4 to create a data frame which has this layout:

```
A F 124 241 068 937 . . . 175 235
.
.
D Q 748 856 300 099 . . . 725 893
```

Since I am extracting 4 columns from data set #1 and only 2 columns from data sets #2 through #19, the new data frame will have 40 columns and 260 rows.

Please let me know if you have tips on how to reformat this data frame. Thank you!

Cheers,
`Di`

Comment: You should provide an exerpt of your actual data, with dput() for instance. You should also provide the desired output and code from your previous attempts, and the outcome of those attempts

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tmp <- data.frame(
  id1 = rep(LETTERS[1:13], 19), 
  id2 = rep(LETTERS[14:26], 19), 
  c1 = seq(1, 19*13, by=1), 
  c2 = seq(19*13, 1, by=-1) 
)
```

In your dataset, you'll have to add a dataset number variable.  Since I have 13 rows for each dataset, I am doing it as follows:

```
tmp <- tmp %>% 
  mutate(ds = rep(1:19, each=13))
```

Then, you can use `pivot_wider()` from the `tidyr` package to reshape your data in the desired fashion.

```
tmp <- tmp %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ds, values_from = c("c1", "c2"))
tmp
# # A tibble: 13 x 40
#   id1   id2    c1_1  c1_2  c1_3  c1_4  c1_5  c1_6  c1_7  c1_8  c1_9 c1_10 c1_11 c1_12 c1_13 c1_14 c1_15 c1_16 c1_17 c1_18
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A     N         1    14    27    40    53    66    79    92   105   118   131   144   157   170   183   196   209   222
# 2 B     O         2    15    28    41    54    67    80    93   106   119   132   145   158   171   184   197   210   223
# 3 C     P         3    16    29    42    55    68    81    94   107   120   133   146   159   172   185   198   211   224
# 4 D     Q         4    17    30    43    56    69    82    95   108   121   134   147   160   173   186   199   212   225
# 5 E     R         5    18    31    44    57    70    83    96   109   122   135   148   161   174   187   200   213   226
# 6 F     S         6    19    32    45    58    71    84    97   110   123   136   149   162   175   188   201   214   227
# 7 G     T         7    20    33    46    59    72    85    98   111   124   137   150   163   176   189   202   215   228
# 8 H     U         8    21    34    47    60    73    86    99   112   125   138   151   164   177   190   203   216   229
# 9 I     V         9    22    35    48    61    74    87   100   113   126   139   152   165   178   191   204   217   230
# 10 J     W        10    23    36    49    62    75    88   101   114   127   140   153   166   179   192   205   218   231
# 11 K     X        11    24    37    50    63    76    89   102   115   128   141   154   167   180   193   206   219   232
# 12 L     Y        12    25    38    51    64    77    90   103   116   129   142   155   168   181   194   207   220   233
# 13 M     Z        13    26    39    52    65    78    91   104   117   130   143   156   169   182   195   208   221   234
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful tip - it looks like this will indeed help me! I am new to R (just started using today) and I am not familiar with its functions. I will try it right away using your example first. And then I will modify it for my use. Thanks so much!

Comment: [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) is an excellent resource that should help you learn some of the ins and outs of the tidyverse.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for sharing this resource @DaveArmstrong! I checked some links posted elsewhere on this website, but those resources are no longer available i.e.  webpage is blank. You have yourself a wonderful rest of the weekend!

Comment: Hi Dave, I noticed that when I attempted the solution you provided, the newly formatted data frame iteratively added all 19 col1's together and then put all 19 col2's together. Is there a way to ensure cols 1 & 2 from each individual data set are adjacent to each other?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone interested in the solution:

DaveArmstrong's solution enabled me to arrange my data horizontally. However, it groups the col 1's together and col 2's together. I wanted to pair cols 1 & 2 from each data set together. I am providing a screenshot of the script (attached to this message) with the additional lines which would need to be implemented in Dave's script.

[Full Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJjeq.png)